# Laravel 4 - User-friendly URLs

Tags: url, laravel, laravel-4, routes

I am using [etrepat/baum](https://github.com/etrepat/baum) composer package to create categories and subcategories in my Laravel 4 application. The problem is that the urls should be different according to if the requested category is a root or a child.

I've got a route specified:

```
Route::get('/store/categories/{urlname}', array(
    'as'  =>  'category',
    'uses'  =>  'StoreController@getCategories'
));
```

As it is now, both categories and subcategories will use this route to get a specific category and go through a url, like:

```
/store/categories/{urlname} -where the urlname might be a category or a subcategory.
```

I have the following query in my controller's function:

```
$category = Category::whereUrl_name($urlname)->with('seo')->first();
```

In database, categories table - if a subcategory is created, it also stores the name for its parent category in a `parent_name` field.

**I am trying to retrieve the categories with hierarchy, so the urls will differ according to:**

*- If the category requested is a root node:*

```
/store/categories/{urlname}
```

*- If the category requested is a child then:*

```
/store/categories/{parent_name}/{urlname}
```

Any ideas on how to solve this type of problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Route

```
Route::get('/store/categories/{urlname}', array(
    'as'  =>  'category',
    'uses'  =>  'StoreController@getCategories'
))->where('urlname', '(.*)?');
```

your function in StoreController

```
public function getCategories($urlname) {    

    $categories = explode('/', $urlname);

    $main = Category::whereUrl_name(end($categories))->with('seo')->first();
    reset($categories);

    if ($main)
    {
        $ancestors = $main->getAncestors();

        $valid = true;

        foreach ($ancestors as $i => $category)
        {
            if ($category->url_name !== $categories[$i])
            {
                $valid = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if ($valid)
        {
            /* continue on with your code here ... */
        }
    }

    App::abort('404');
}
```

Comment: This is not exactly what I am looking for. As your solution uses a second route to a another function to get the subcategories (getSubcategories). Also this will have a url like:      /store/subcategories/{parent_name}/{urlname}.

Comment: I thought these two routes were your self defined goal. You should clarify your goal then. So you only want that first route? And the {urlname} can be a category or subcategory but we don't know which right? So what is your question then? Which answer do you expect from your function in case of a category and which in case of a subcategory? Maybe you can provide an example data in your question?

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is to make the urls: example.com/store/categories/[category_urlname] (Parent)
example.com/store/categories/[parent_name]/[category_urlname] (Child, Has Parent). The problem now is either if is a parent or a child it will use: example.com/store/categories/[category_urlname]

Comment: Sorry I still don't get you. If you want to call `example.com/category/[parent]/[child]` then you will need a route for it. Or do you want to create links? I don't understand what your goal is.

Comment: I found a very similar question here: http://laravel.io/forum/03-11-2014-how-to-make-urls-seo-friendly-with-nested-set-model

Comment: so what is wrong with that solution posted in the laravel.io forum?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66130/discussion-between-peh-and-cchacholiades).